# Apache CXF, Spring-boot, one service, one WSDL with different listening port

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have a application with spring boot and apache cxf and java.
It seems that one application should be launched as two processes. So I thought I had to open two server ports. One is 8090, the other is 8080.
Also there is one service using one WSDL.
How can the client differentiate the different listening ports of this server when calling this service from the client?

Comment: Would you explain more details(or maybe it is better to add a diagram photo)?
Is it is the requirement to serve on two different ports? The controller, service layer is the same? in this application, you have a client which needs to connect to another server?

Comment: For example, assuming there are 3 clients, each client must provide the same vo to the server. This means that only one WSDL is used. However, since one client makes many calls, it is necessary to create another server that only responds to this client. These two servers perform the exact same function. (Because it is defined in one WSDL) In that case, there should be two listening ports. I want to manage these two servers with one WSDL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to think about **scaling**. It means that you want to **`make the system can handle more incoming requests`** .
There are several scaling solutions instead of serving two different ports, depending on your infrastructure and your needs. Scaling can be done Vertically or Horizontally.

[image: Scaling methods]

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52084649/601288) that describe spring boot scaling in detail.

Comment: @creativeshim if it answers your question, you need to mark it as an **Answer**.